# How-to: Field-level permissions for referenced user in Drupal

Tags: permissions, drupal-7, field

I'm working on a quite complex user permission setup in Drupal: If a user is referenced in a node (user reference field), he/she should be able to view all fields and edit certain fields. If the user is a simple authenticed user, he/she has no update right but could view some fields (but not all of them!). Would it be possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Should be fairly straightforward with Drupal. Two places you'll need to update: 1) when users are viewing the node and 2) when users are editing the node

I would start by creating a small function to check the user's permission for a specific node - which would basically check if user is referenced by the node as you mentioned.

Then, Step 1 can use the node_view_hook, call that function you defined to check for permissions and hide fields (fields that will be displayed are on within $node->content). Basically, you can hide fields by unsetting them here.

Step 2, fairly similar to step 1, using form_alter_hook though. Check for the user's permission and then just use the #access attribute to hide each one of the fields the user isn't supposed to be able to edit.

Hope this helps!

Comment: However I'm not a very experienced module developer, I will try. Thanks!